# jquery datePicker is not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i am trying to use Jquery datepicker but its not working on my Zendframework 2 application.

below is the js classes that i called:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<?php echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min')

 ->prependStylesheet($this->basePath() . '/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom')
```

i then made a seperate page for the datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('jquery is being called');

    $('#date_from').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd- M-yy'  ,
        minDate:0,
            showAnin: 'show',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#date_to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );

                 }
   });
```

the alert worked; so the jquery is actually being called; but i dont know why the datepicker is not working.

is there any advice that you can give me to find out why its not working.

thank you in advance for your assistance.

**ALSO**

i also looked at my firebug console but no error report came up

```
echo' <input type="date" value="" id="date_from" name="WorkerTimeTables[availableFrom]">';
```

**UPDATE**

IT WORKS NOW!. i forgot to put the js extension when i called the js files.

thank you everyone for your kind attention.

Comment: There is no jquery 1.10.4. Try `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Do you load this input via AJAX? Or rephrazed, on the document.ready, does this element exist?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> Try using this code ,instead of Cake php code to include lib.

Comment: Your zend includes don't have file extensions are they not required?

Comment: hi martin. i hard coded the element. so, it does indeed exist

Comment: hi everyone; its works now. thank you to Wilmer for pointing out that i had not put the extension

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('jquery is being called');

    $('#date_from').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd- M-yy',
        minDate:0,
        showAnim: 'show',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                $("#date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
 });
```

it works

[Jsfiddle --- link](http://jsfiddle.net/mR7HE/)

Comment: Hello dbucki. i tried it but nothing happened. i also looked at my firebug console but no error reports came up

Comment: Downvote because you didn't actually change any **code**, only some identation. You can add a million more spaces and tabs, or remove all of them (is called minimizing), it will work exactly the same :)

Comment: show diff beetwen original, datepicker method was not closed in question

I added link to JsFiddle and you can see it works